# Is it possible to extract mutation testing results for every test method with Pit Mutation Test

Tags: unit-testing, mutation-testing, pitest

I know that [PIT Mutation Test framework](https://pitest.org/) can export mutation coverage information based on the test suite or the test class. However, I was wondering if there is an option to extract or export mutation coverage information based on the test case methods (test cases under the @Test annotation), so that I can see which test cases are written well and which are not. If it is not possible, the simplest solution that comes to my mind is commenting all the test methods and uncommenting only one of the test methods, run it and export the information. I wanted to know if there is an elegant solution.

Note: I know that [MuJava](https://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/mujava/) provides such information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the (badly/un)documented matrix feature.

Assuming you're using maven you'll need to add

```
<fullMutationMatrix>true</fullMutationMatrix>
<outputFormats>
 <param>XML</param>
</outputFormats>
```

To your pom.

The XML output will then contain pipe separated test names in the killing test nodes.

```
<killingTests>foo|foo2</killingTests>
<succeedingTests>bar</succeedingTests>
```

Comment: I also have a very small question. What is the difference between "killingTests" and "succeedingTests"?